# How to force app that has an main activity with category home set to close

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-button, home-button

i'm trying to develope an app for a tablet (ICS 4.0.3) that will be used in public places like bar, resturant ecc..

The user that uses that tablet ( so my application ) could not go in home and only administrator, setting a code, can go out.

What i've done is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Activity actual;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
           finish(); // it doesn't work 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing!
    }
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

ADMINISTRATION DIALOG:

TEST1: // application is relaunched

```
Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(homeIntent);
```

TEST2: // application is relaunched

```
System.exit(0);
```

TEST3: // it open settings (o.O)

```
Intent h = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
h.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
h.putExtra("EXIT", true);
context.startActivity(h);
```

My problem is that i can't go out from application.. how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

In TEST3 you've only provided `ACTION_MAIN` in the Intent. Android looks for apps that can handle this action and finds a long list of them. How should it know that it should launch yours?

I assume you've set your app as a HOME-screen replacement. Try adding this to the code for TEST3:

```
h.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```